# How to create a Silverlight application that interacts with a C++ web service?

Tags: c++, silverlight, web-services, wcf-ria-services

I have a C++ web service that needs to send/receive data from a Silverlight client.
Can I still use the WCF RIA client or do I need to use the sockets library directly?
Note that I'm pretty flexible on using HTTP or not, and I even prefer not to use the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Now this is just me thinking outloud here. But I'd assume that since you're using a C++ web service you're too low level to be doing anything WCF based (as WCF is usually a C# thing).

As far as using a sockets library directly, I think that a silverlight app can't do that for security reasons. Sockets are mainly for a client app that you have built yourself. But silverlight is a web client, So I would think that you'd only be left to use http requests.

Comment: Yes there is a socket interface: http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx

Comment: ahh you're absolutely right it looks like a silverlight app can connect via sockets to the host it got downloaded from. sorry about that!